# Core graphics draw concentric circles and fill the gap between them

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, cgcontext, quartz-2d

I need to draw 2 circles and fill the area between inner and outer circle with yellow color, that is the area which is not in the intersection. How do I do that using core graphics? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.setFillColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    let radius = min(rect.width/2, rect.height/2)

    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height/2)
    path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: 2*radius, height: 2*radius))
    context.addPath(path)

   // context.drawPath(using: .fill)

    let path2 = CGMutablePath()
    path2.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - radius/2, y: center.y - radius/2, width: radius, height: radius))


    context.addPath(path2)

    context.clip()

    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
  let path = CGMutablePath()
    let radius = min(rect.width/2, rect.height/2)

    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height/2)
    path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: 2*radius, height: 2*radius))


    let path2 = CGMutablePath()
    path2.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - radius/2, y: center.y - radius/2, width: radius, height: radius))

   path.addPath(path2)
    context.addPath(path)

    context.drawPath(using: .eoFill)


//inner part
   let path3 = CGMutablePath()
    path3.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: center.x - radius/2, y: center.y - radius/2, width: radius, height: radius))
      context.addPath(path3)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
context.fillPath()
```

Comment: It works, but how do we extend it if I need to fill inner circle with a different color?

Comment: add another path like above.